# how to say : "Pole street lights and wall street lights" (?)

Tags: phrase-request

It's a picture description, I just have to mention the two kinds of "Lampposts"
 (on a pole and on wall) connected with a conjunction "and". How can I do?

I tried:
"**Pole street lights and wall street lights**"/
"**Lampposts and wall street lights**"/
"**Street lights on pole and on wall**"

Comment: Picture please.

Comment: I cannot share the picture here, there is copyright on the content. 
My need is just to "mention" (subsequently) the two kinds of street lights (on pole and on wall). 
In the picture, there are shown the suggested new shape of lampposts to install on the streets of a town.
 I just have to say "Street lights on pole and on wall . (full stop)". Would it be correct?

Comment: In the UK, street lights are normally put up and maintained by *local government*. Since most *buildings* are privately owned, a local council wouldn't really want to get bogged down with the contractual implications of attaching street lights to them, arranging power supply and control systems, etc. In short, actual (publicly-funded) ***street lights*** are mounted on ***poles***, whereas private buildings may have ***floodlights, security lights,*** or ***courtesy lights*** mounted on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the picture, I can only define the three types of streetlights you might be talking about.

"Lampposts" are poles with a light on top that resembles a lantern or globe. The light goes in all directions horizontally, and possibly up.

"Pole mounted street lights" are poles that have a directional light at the top that points down. Usually there is a bend or a second pole branching off the vertical pole, but there can be a light fixture at the top of one straight pole that points down.

"Wall mounted street lights" are a pole that is attached to a wall that goes horizontal or upward sloping and ends in a directional light that points down.

If your picture has the second two, then you can either say "Pole mounted street lights and wall mounted street lights" or shorten it to "pole mounted and wall mounted street lights."

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole lot of outside lighting; there are **wall-mounted lights (or wall bracket street lights, wall lights), street lights, lampposts, street lamps, heritage lights, bollard lights, recessed wall lights, path lights spotlights, post lamps and pole lights.**

We may name all of the **outside (outdoor/external) lighting**.

I would consider *"pole light and wall-mounted lights for outside (street) lighting"*

Or call them *"street lights and outdoor wall-mounted lights"*

Another possible way to say it is *"outdoor pole/wall-mounted lights (lamps)"* or *"pole/wall mounted street lights"*